# Is there a CSS selector for element without any class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector for element without any class? For example in HTML

```html
<section>Section A</section>
<section class="special">Section B</section>
<section class="">Section C</section>
```

I would like to select Section A (or maybe Section A and Section C, it does not matter that much), by saying something like

```
section:not(.*) { color: gray }
```

I understand that I could define it to section and reset it back in all particular classes, like in

```
section { color: gray } 
section.special { color: black }
```

but this is not what I want, because it is not very manageable once the styles get complex and in some cases it is hard to do the "reset" properly (of course not in this simplified example).

Comment: you can select element by section:nth-child(1){ background : red;} and apply effect

Comment: thanks for editing the question. I mentioned sass because I am happy enough even with sass only solution. Pure css would be better however.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Sass because whatever selector you write *must* be valid CSS in the end.  The tag was removed for a reason.  Do not add it back in.

Comment: Your idea somehwat goes against the ideas of inheritance and specificity in CSS. Instead of considering the styling of `.special` as a "reset", you should see it as a "refinement" applied to a subset of your `section` selection. The solutions given to your question won't give you optimal performance and will make things more complicated. (By the way, your first CSS example looks shorter because you omit : `section { color: black; }`).

Comment: @Nicolas Le Thierry d'Ennequin: The reason `section { color: black; }` is omitted is because it's not needed in the first place - presumably it's taking on the default already. The second example clearly shows the redundancy of setting a color for all sections and then having to remove it from every possible class that the sections can have. I don't understand why you think the first example would be more complicated. As for performance, between that and maintainability, you only get to pick one.

Comment: I'm sure you have a really good reason for needing this, but I'd warn against it because it must be incredibly hard to maintain, and selecting all divs without a class isn't far away from just selecting a div.  if anyone ever reads the code they'll really struggle to understand it, if you use it I would comment it for sure.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

With `section:not([class])` you select every section without the class attribute. Unfortunately, it won't select those sections with an empty class attribute value. So in addition, we have to exclude these sections:

```css
section:not([class]) { /* every section without class - but won't select Section C */
  color: red;
}

section[class=""] { /* selects only Section C */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section>Section A</section>
<section class="special">Section B</section>
<section class="">Section C</section>
```

#### Further reading

- [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=attribute%20selector)
- [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: Neither matches `<section class="      ">4</section>` which also could be said to have no class.

Comment: or `class=" , , , , "` for that matter, or just any `class` value without correct classes.

Comment: Can you confirm that `:not([class])` selects elements with an empty class attribute?

Comment: IF the `:not([class])` part is standard, than this is good enough for me. I understand that there is infinite possibilities how to screw it with empty classes, but the only thing I might practically consider is class with no character at all.

Comment: @Senthe - A comma is a valid class name. so such an element does not have no class and `[class~=","]` will match it.

Comment: Can anyone tell `if :not([class])` is standard?

Comment: Cannot agree more with you, @AndréDion ! W3Schools has done too much damage to the web development community, and some people still think they are associated with W3C.

Comment: @AndréDion thanks for the info. Didn't know about [that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: @Alohci: And, more importantly, so will `.\,`. (More importantly, because `[class~=","]` doesn't carry classname semantics, although the rules on whitespace delimiters happen to be the same.)

Comment: @gorn: You can easily find this out for yourself. The links are right there in the answer.

Comment: @BoltClock - where, in CSS selectors, is "classname semantics" defined, and what practical difference does it make?

Comment: @Alohci: css3-selectors calls the period notation an alternative to the ~= notation and goes further to say that UAs can map whichever is deemed the "class" attribute in an XML-based language to the class selector. selectors-4 states plainly that it "represents an element belonging to the class identified by the identifier, as defined by the document language", citing the class atttribute in HTML, SVG and MathML as examples. In those languages, it makes no practical difference (if they consider sequences of any non-whitespace characters to be valid classnames).

Comment: @BoltClock - Oh I get it. So what you're saying is that in other XML languages, `[class~=","]` doesn't automatically imply that it is matching the *class* of the element, just an attribute with the name "class". Yes, agreed.