# Change color of a tag withing body which don't have any class

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the color of a tag of body which don't have any class using css or jquery. Check the example bellow :

```
<body>
  <a href="#" class="one">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="three">Three</a>
  <a href="#" class="four">Four</a>
</body>
```

i have to write the css using which one  a tag color will be change. Number of a tag may be more than fours.

Comment: Hello, give me the link..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355486/is-there-a-css-selector-for-element-without-any-class