# CSS selector when an item has no class

Tags: css

I am trying to target all instances of an h tag but only when it has no class.

For example:

```
<h1 class="class1">First</h1>
<h1 class="class2">Second</h1>
<h1>Third</h1>
```

In this instance I only want to target Third but not the others - I found an answer ([Is there a CSS selector for element without any class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355486/is-there-a-css-selector-for-element-without-any-class)) which referred to [class=""] selector but that only seems to work on:

```
<h1 class="">Third</h1>
```

It is not practical to go through and list all the instances of classes and then reference them using :not so is there another way?

I accept that this is being made worse through the use of !important etc in the current CSS on some of the h1 classes but I have inherited this and I don't have the ability to start from scratch.

Comment: `:not([class]), [class='']`???

Comment: If you have `!important` in the existing css and you can't get rid of it, you have no choice but to put `!important` in your own css as well, AND to make sure your stylesheet is included after the existing one.

Comment: If you look closely, the answer there shows how it works for when there is no class at all, as well as what is required when there is a class attribute that is blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you use h1: not ([class]) this tag search all.
```

If there are many !important you should use it in the new css and this new css place it at the end of all .css

```
Example:

<h1 class="class1">First</h1>
<h1>Second</h1>
<h1>Third</h1>

h1:not([class]) { 
  color: red;
}
```